# where does JAX-WS method publish publishes to

Tags: java, web-services

I don't have local server installed on my machine but I am able to run and publish below web service. How is it working?

```
 //Endpoint publisher
    public class HelloWorldPublisher{

        public static void main(String[] args) {
           Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8888/ws/hello", new HelloWorldImpl());
        }

    }
```

tested by using

```
http://localhost:8888/ws/hello?wsdl
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a built in  Default Http sever in the SDK. The publish methods starts the default server and publishes to that server.

Comment: ok thanks, what is the path to the http server in that JDK package

Comment: com.sun.net.httpserver  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/package-summary.html